# Optimizing a stack holding N items to meet as many permutations of strings

Tags: string, algorithm, permutation

I want to find an algorithm that does the following:

I have a list permutations

Each one holds between 1 to 4 strings (repetition is allowed)

Same string can appear in many permutations

I also have  stack that can hold up to N strings

An optimized stack is a list of N strings that suffices the most permutations from the list

For example,
Say I have the following permutations:

1. [aaa] [aaa] [bbb] [ccc]
2. [aaa] [ddd] [ddd]
3. [ccc]

And the N is 4

The optimized stack would be [aaa] [aaa] [bbb] [ccc]
Because this stack suffices 2 permutations

P.s. if the same string appears more K times in a permutation it should also appear at least K times in the stack in order to suffice that permutation

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm to find the optimized stack given the N (size of the stack) and a list of permutations

Comment: From your example, you mean that : 1) if we have same string in permutation A and B, we take only 1.  2) we should take the repetition in consideration, mean if we have the same string in permutation A with 2 repetition ,  and in permutation B with 3 repetition so we take the all 3  that are in the permutation B.  is that what you search for ?

Comment: if the input is  1) [aaa] [bbb] [bbb] [ccc] , 2) [aaa] [aaa] [ddd] [ddd] , 3) [ccc] [ccc] ,  How the result should be ?  is the following output correct :  [aaa] [aaa] [bbb] [bbb] [ddd] [ddd] [ccc] [ccc] ?